# using rvest to scrape a review from particular html pagein R

Tags: r, rvest

i am scraping page [tata safari discription](http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/official-new-car-reviews/171841-tata-safari-storme-varicor-400-official-review.html) for getting reviews and user comments. i am using selector gadget for getting css tag. things i have done so far is :

```
teambhp <- read_html("http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/official-new-car-reviews/171841-tata-safari-storme-varicor-400-official-review.html")
titles <- teambhp %>% html_node("hr+ div , i ,strong u , #posts ") %>% html_text()
```

but it is only saving one title inn titles variable. and giving warning as below.

```
Warning message:
In node_find_one(x$node, x$doc, xpath = xpath, nsMap = ns) :
23 matches for .//hr/following-sibling::*[name() = 'div' and (position() = 1)] | .//i | .//strong/descendant-or-self::*/u | .//*[@id = 'posts']: 
using first
```

i want all 23 to be saved in list. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `help("html_node)`:

> html_node vs html_nodes
>
> html_node is like [[ it always extracts exactly one element. When given a list of nodes, html_node will always return a list of the same length, the length of html_nodes might be longer or shorter.

You need to replace it with `html_nodes()` (notice the s):

```
titles <- teambhp %>% html_nodes("hr+ div , i ,strong u , #posts ") %>% html_text()
```